# Nvidia-smi doesn't show GPU Memory Usage and full path for Process Names

Tags: windows-10, gpu, nvidia

I ran the command `nvidia-smi` on my `windows 10` PC.

- Why does it display GPU Memory Usage as "N/A"?
- How do I access full path for each Process names that is active? (right now it only shows a part of the path)

Are there any alternative ways to access such information other than `nvidia-smi`?

```
C:\Users\ks>nvidia-smi
Sun Nov 29 09:04:35 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 445.87       Driver Version: 445.87       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1650   WDDM  | 00000000:08:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 50%   31C    P8     8W /  75W |    506MiB /  4096MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU                  PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|                                                                  Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                 1164    C+G   Insufficient Permissions        N/A      |
|    0                 2140    C+G   ...8bbwe\Microsoft.Notes.exe    N/A      |
|    0                 3188    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe         N/A      |
|    0                 4492    C+G   ...me\Application\chrome.exe    N/A      |
|    0                 6156    C+G   ...artMenuExperienceHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0                 7844    C+G   ...y\ShellExperienceHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0                10156    C+G   ...b3d8bbwe\WinStore.App.exe    N/A      |
|    0                11340    C+G   ...lPanel\SystemSettings.exe    N/A      |
|    0                12932    C+G   ...es.TextInput.InputApp.exe    N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: On WDDM systems, the NVIDIA driver doesn't manage GPU memory. The WDDM subsystem does. That is why you don't see memory usage. But I am really struggling to see how a GPU driver utility usage question is on-topic for [SO]. You would be better served asking at the NVIDIA support forums, or maybe superuser

Comment: Solution on Windows: Run Sysinternals Process Explorer as Administrator, then switch on columns "GPU Dedicated"  and "GPU Committed" to see per-process GPU memory usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - Why does it display GPU Memory Usage as "N/A"?

As *talonmies* answered, **on WDDM systems, the NVIDIA driver doesn't manage GPU memory**. The WDDM subsystem does.

You can check this by running a command `nvidia-smi --help-query-compute-apps`, then it shows the reason under `"used_gpu_memory" or "used_memory"`.
Mine says `Not available on Windows when running in WDDM mode because Windows KMD manages all the memory not NVIDIA driver.`

> - How do I access full path for each Process names that is active? (right now it only shows a part of the path)

You can access the full paths by running a command `nvidia-smi --query-compute-apps=pid,process_name,used_memory --format=csv`.

Comment: Solution on Windows: Run Sysinternals Process Explorer as Administrator, then switch on columns "GPU Dedicated"  and "GPU Committed" to see per-process GPU memory usage.